# I have a problem in flutter about androidManifest.xml

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmZ46.png)I have a problem with Flutter using Environment (VScode) related to the AndroidManifest.xml file, as shown in the picture. I have tried various solutions to resolve the issue, but none of them have been successful. I hope you assist me in resolving this problem.

Comment: You could start by showing us the whole file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add receiver tag between application tag. Refer this image - [image: flutter_local_notification_manifestfile_setup]

You have added the receiver tag outside the whole  tag may be that's why you got that error.

Refer this link for more - [AndroidManifest_set_up](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#androidmanifestxml-setup)

Answer (score 0):

I performed an update, and the error has been resolved.

(flutter_local_notifications: ^6.0.0 to flutter_local_notifications: ^17.0.0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).